# Vuetify v-calendar next day

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, hour, vcalendar

I'm trying to create a v-calendar with vuetify.
The problem is that I can't start at 10:00 and show 3:00 the next day.
How can I display it until 3 o'clock the next day?

```html
<v-calendar
  ref="calendar"
  v-model="focus"
  color="primary"
  type="category"
  category-show-all
  :categories="categories"
  :events="events"
  :event-color="getEventColor"
  first-interval=10
  interval-minutes= 60  
  @change="fetchEvents()"
></v-calendar>
```

[image: The problem photo]

[image: The problem photo]

Comment: Thank you for your correction.  I will ask questions like this in the future!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution but it's a bit hacky (doesn't seem natively supported by Vuetify). First, you'll need to use the prop `interval-count`

> The number of intervals to display in the day view.

When you use this to show hours past midnight, the calendar will grow vertically to accommodate the additional hours, but will still not show the interval labels for those hours.

If we use another prop called `show-interval-label`, it takes a function that:

> Checks if a given day and time should be displayed in the interval gutter of the day view.

Using the props together:

```js
first-interval="10"
interval-minutes="60"
interval-count="18"
:show-interval-label="showInterval"
```

Here I define a method `showInterval` and in showInterval if I console.log all the intervals it receives, the first interval that is **not** displayed (1:00am) looks like this:

```js
{
  "date": "2022-11-14",
  "time": "25:00",
  "year": 2022,
  "month": 11,
  "day": 14,
  "weekday": 1,
  "hour": 26,
  "minute": 0,
  "hasDay": true,
  "hasTime": true,
  "past": false,
  "present": false,
  "future": true
}
```

Even if we `return true` for all intervals, the intervals after midnight still won't be displayed on the calendar. That is because the v-calendar template code **knows** after midnight it should only display intervals for the *next* day, but the interval object itself still has properties defining it using the previous day (`date`, `day`, `weekday`, etc)

To get these intervals to display we have to modify the object to look like this instead:

```js
{
  "date": "2022-11-15",
  "time": "1:00",
  "year": 2022,
  "month": 11,
  "day": 15,
  "weekday": 2,
  "hour": 1,
  "minute": 0,
  "hasDay": true,
  "hasTime": true,
  "past": false,
  "present": false,
  "future": true
}
```

The full code for doing so is below which I also included in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/KKeqxBg?editors=1010)

```js
showInterval(dateObj) {
  console.log('dateObj', dateObj);
  if (dateObj.hour > 24) {
    const extraDays = Math.floor(dateObj.hour / 24);
    const newHour = dateObj.hour === 24 ? 24 : dateObj.hour % 24;
    const newDay = dateObj.weekday + extraDays === 7 ? 7 : (dateObj.weekday + extraDays) % 7;
    dateObj.hour = newHour;
    dateObj.weekday = newDay;
    dateObj.day = dateObj.day + extraDays;
    dateObj.date = this.addDays(dateObj.date, extraDays);
    dateObj.time = this.subtractTime(dateObj.time, extraDays);
  }
  return true;
},
addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
},
subtractTime(time, days) {
  const timeArr = time.split(':');
  const newHour = Number(timeArr[0]) - 24 * days;
  return newHour + ':' + timeArr.slice(1).join();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It was very helpful!  I will try it as soon as I get home!